# Getting Excel to average a large data set every 49-50 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am working with a large data set. Here is a picture of the first few lines.

[image: here]

About every 50 rows the cycle number increases by 1. However, the program that is used for data acquisition sometimes misses collection ending up with 49 points per cycle vs 50 points per cycle.

What I am trying to do is average each columns data for each individual cycle but I need to somehow account for the change in the number of points per cycle.

I have been using:

```
AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$2,(ROW()-2)*50,0,50,1))
```

to but I can't figure out how to make this dynamic when the amount of rows in each cycle changes.

Comment: Put the cycles in a column and use AVERAGEIFS(), or use a pivot table.

Comment: How would I use AVERAGEIFS() to offset my averages depending on the number of points per cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 or Office 2019 you can use AverageIf().

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10)
```

In earlier versions of Excel that do not have this function, you can use this approach:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$10,0)):INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$10,1)))
```

The screenshot shows both formulas in action.

[image]

Edit: if you want the average to show only on a row with a new cycle number, encase the whole formula in an IF statement, like

```
=if(A2<>A1,AVERAGE(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$10,0)):INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$10,1))),"")
```

Comment: `AVERAGEIF` goes back to Excel 2007

Comment: Is there a way I can orient the data so that the cycle and the average are shown only once?

Comment: I added a variation of the formula to my answer.